# Linux - Upgrading the BIOS using an EXE

Tags: executable, bios, firmware

When a bios update is only available via .exe, what's the easiest way to update the bios on a computer running Linux exclusively?

Many times I've had to install Windows 10 onto a computer just long enough to do a bios update.

I'm not aware of any version of windows that would allow me to boot from a thumb drive, dvd, or cd. Also, I've never figured out how to install windows onto an external hard drive unless the PC has an eSATA port.

Maybe wine can install a bios.exe upgrade, but I'm apprehensive to try it on such a critical task.

I wish Windows 10 had a "LIVE CD" like most Linux distributions offer. Maybe I can boot with DOS, but it is 2019 and I'm not sure that still works on modernly created EXEs.

Comment: While it might be dependent on the specific hardware (for example Dell computers/servers somewhat support updating BIOS via USB stick), [this ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flashing_BIOS_from_Linux) article can give you some tips.

Comment: Not an answer, but sometimes the manufacturer supplies a bootable iso for firmware upgrades, allowing you to bypass this mess

Comment: My times that is a DOS .EXE, booting with FreeDOS works